# jq: Getting two levels of keys

Tags: jq

I have some json data that looks like:

```
{
  "p": {
    "d": {
      "a" : {
        "r": "foo",
        "g": 1
      },
      "b": {
        "r": "bar",
        "g": 2
      }
    },
    "c": {
      "e": {
        "r": "baz",
        "g": 1
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I want something like:

```json
{
  "d": [ 
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "c": [
    "e"
  ]
}
```

I can get the list of keys on the first level under "p" with `jq '.p|keys'`, and the structure and keys on the second level with `jq '.p|map(.|keys)'`, but I can't figure out how to combine it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `map_values` instead of `map` to map the values of a JSON object while preserving the keys:

```bash
jq '.p | map_values(keys)'
```

On jq versions lower than 1.5, `map_values` is not defined: instead, you can use `[]|=`:

```bash
jq '.p | . []|= keys'
```

Comment: Apparently `map_values` doesn't exist in the version (1.4) I have here.

Comment: Try `jq '.p | . []|= keys'`

Comment: Well, if I recall correctly, `map_values` is defined as `def map_values(f): . []|= f;` in jq's standard library, so both answers are equivalent; the reason the first one didn't work for you is that you're using an old version of jq. That said, I'll append this to the existing answer.

Answer (score 14):

### In general

#### Top level keys:

`curl -s https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/atty | jq '. |= keys'`

```json
[
  "categories",
  "crate",
  "keywords",
  "versions"
]
```

### Two levels of keys:

`curl -s https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/atty | jq '.| map_values(keys)'`

```json
{
  "crate": [
    "badges",
    "categories",
    "created_at",
    "description",
    "documentation",
    "downloads",
    "exact_match",
    "homepage",
    "id",
    "keywords",
    "links",
    "max_version",
    "name",
    "newest_version",
    "recent_downloads",
    "repository",
    "updated_at",
    "versions"
  ],
  "versions": [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16
  ],
  "keywords": [
    0,
    1,
    2
  ],
  "categories": []
}
```

### Method versions

```bash
topLevelJsonKeys() {
 curl -s $1 | jq '. |= keys'
  # EXAMPLE: 
  # topLevelJsonKeys https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/atty
}

topLevelJsonKeys2() {
  curl -s $1 | jq '.| map_values(keys)'
  # EXAMPLE: 
  # topLevelJsonKeys2 https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/atty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which uses **reduce** and **setpath**

```
  .p
| reduce keys[] as $k (
     .
   ; setpath([$k]; .[$k] | keys)
)
```