# Read in multi-level YAML / JSON to bash variables

Tags: json, bash, yaml, jq, yq

Say I have a yaml file, `example.yaml`:

```
networks:
  net:
    driver: overlay
dockerfiles:
  nodeapp: |
    FROM node:18-alpine
    WORKDIR /$NAME
services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "337:337"
  pinger:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nodeapp
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
```

I can convert to JSON using [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), and then set the top level entries as variables with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
eval $(yq e example.yaml -j | jq -r '..? | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value|tostring)')

echo $services
{registry:{image:registry:2,ports:[5000:5000]},pinger:{build:{context:.,dockerfile:nodeapp},deploy:{replicas:3}}}
```

However, I cannot seem to get `jq` to recursively go into the objects and set variables, so that `echo $services_pinger_dockerfile` gives `"nodeapp"` for example.

I've seen in the docs that there is a [recursion operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..). Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

---

There are similar questions. But none that I found dealing with multilevel YAML/JSON to shell variables in this way.

[jq: Getting two levels of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627427/jq-getting-two-levels-of-keys)

[Extract JSON value to shell variable using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981265/extract-json-value-to-shell-variable-using-jq)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121718/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting-in-linux

[Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools#1955555)

[How can I parse a YAML file from a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script)

[How to read yaml file into bash associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001044/how-to-read-yaml-file-into-bash-associative-array)

Comment: It's not really clear what your expected result should be. The reason we need these fancier formats is that not everything can be flattened into a simple series of name-value pairs where the names are unique.

Comment: For this approach, there's no need to switch to `jq` if you are already in `yq` - unless you want to use `@sh`, which you aren't currently, although it feels like you should.

Comment: @tripleee I'm experimenting with defining an entire docker swarm app (all info required for all build and deployment steps) in a single yaml file. I'll have a bash script to read the file and run a series of `docker` commands. Hence the need for bash variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not process it directly with `yq`?

```bash
eval $(yq e '.. | select(. == "*") | {(path | join("_")): . style="double"} ' example.yaml | sed -E 's/(.*): (.*)/\1=\2/g')
echo $services_pinger_build_dockerfile
```

`yq` command was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303779/347964), see there for details.

The appended `sed` rewrites `a_b: "c"` into `a_b="c"`, so we can then `eval` it in bash. I do not use the technique you show because it would cause the values to not be quoted in the output, which is bad especially for multi-line strings.

The code outputs `nodeapp`.

Comment: Great answer, it does miss the `echo $services_registry_ports` case though (admittedly I didn't directly address that case in the question).

Comment: @Lee You'd need to do `echo $services_registrey_ports_0` etc, the index is part of the path. You might be wondering whether you can put them into a bash array and that's definitely possible with enough `yq` magic, but mind that sequences in YAML can contain nested mappings where that wouldn't work.

Comment: Got it, thanks, and yes I was wondering re. array; `yq` magic seems to be a deep rabbit hole. A great tool!